# How to turn a float number like 293.4662543 into 293.47 in python?

Tags: python, number-formatting

How to shorten the float result I got? I only need 2 digits after the dot. Sorry I really don't know how to explain this better in English...

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to change the value of the result for possible later use or just change what decimal string it is converted into?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

From The Floating-Point Guide's [Python cheat sheet](http://floating-point-gui.de/languages/python/):

```
"%.2f" % 1.2399 # returns "1.24"
"%.3f" % 1.2399 # returns "1.240"
"%.2f" % 1.2 # returns "1.20"
```

Using round() is the wrong thing to do, because floats are [binary fractions](http://floating-point-gui.de/formats/binary/) which *cannot* represent decimal digits accurately.

If you need to do calculations with decimal digits, use the `Decimal` type in the `decimal` module.

Comment: Supposing you need to store that result for future use, would something like x = "%.2f" work, or how do you still use that data, rather then simply printing it (as I have seen others below use the print function) EDIT: I should probably just follow your link, sorry. EDIT again, sorry still not sure how the original question I asked works with that syntax. +1 as your way looks good!

Comment: @onaclov2000: as I wrote: if you need to work with decimal data, you should be using a decimal data type instead of float.

Answer (score 32):

If you want a number, use the [`round()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#round) function:

```
>>> round(12.3456, 2)
12.35
```

(but +1 for Michael's answer re. the `Decimal` type.)

If you want a string:

```
>>> print "%.2f" % 12.34567
12.35
```

Answer (score 10):

One way:

```
>>> number = 1
>>> '{:.2f}'.format(number) #1.00
>>> '{:.3f}'.format(number) #1.000
```

second way:

```
>>> '%.2f' % number #1.00
>>> '%.3f' % number #1.000
```

see "format python"

Answer (score 9):

From :
 [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round)
round(x[, n])
Return the floating point value x rounded to n digits after the decimal point. If n is omitted, it defaults to zero. The result is a floating point number. Values are rounded to the closest multiple of 10 to the power minus n; if two multiples are equally close, rounding is done away from 0 (so. for example, round(0.5) is 1.0 and round(-0.5) is -1.0).

Note The behavior of round() for floats can be surprising: for example, round(2.675, 2) gives 2.67 instead of the expected 2.68. This is not a bug: it’s a result of the fact that most decimal fractions can’t be represented exactly as a float. See Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations for more information.

Looks like round (293.466....[, 2]) would do it,

Answer (score 7):

I hope this will help.

```
def do(*args):
    formattedList = [float("{:.2f}".format(num)) for num in args]
    _result =(sum(formattedList))
    result = round(_result,2)
    return result


print(do(23.2332,45.24567,67,54.27))
```

Result:

```
189.75
```

Answer (score 6):

`x = round(293.4662543, 2)`

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> print "%.2f" % 293.44612345
293.45
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need numbers like *2.3k* or *12M*, this function does the job:

```
def get_shortened_integer(number_to_shorten):
    """ Takes integer and returns a formatted string """
    trailing_zeros = floor(log10(abs(number_to_shorten)))
    if trailing_zeros < 3:
        # Ignore everything below 1000
        return trailing_zeros
    elif 3 <= trailing_zeros <= 5:
        # Truncate thousands, e.g. 1.3k
        return str(round(number_to_shorten/(10**3), 1)) + 'k'
    elif 6 <= trailing_zeros <= 8:
        # Truncate millions like 3.2M
        return str(round(number_to_shorten/(10**6), 1)) + 'M'
    else:
        raise ValueError('Values larger or equal to a billion not supported')
```

Results:

```
>>> get_shortened_integer(2300)
2.3k # <-- str

>>> get_shortened_integer(1300000)
1.3M # <-- str
```