# Python: what to do if the number is too long?

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert `poloar` into `x-y` panel:

```
df['x']=df.apply(lambda x: x['speed'] * math.cos(math.radians(x['degree'])),axis=1)
df['y']=df.apply(lambda x: x['speed'] * math.sin(math.radians(x['degree'])),axis=1)
df.head()
```

This produces
[image]

The problem is that the `x` is too long, how can I make it shorter?

I find in [How to turn a float number like 293.4662543 into 293.47 in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914725/how-to-turn-a-float-number-like-293-4662543-into-293-47-in-python), I can do `"%.2f" % 1.2399`, but if this is a good approach?

Comment: Perhaps this belongs on [**Code Review**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @cqcn1991: Your problem is not well defined. You've already found how you can truncate to a specific number of decimal digits. If you're not sure that's "a good approach" then what are the actual constraints on your solution?

Comment: @DanielPryden, I just feel a bit of weird for this. I mean, if most of the time, number looks this long, then everyone need to truancate them? Isn't that repetative? So I'm wondering if there is any other approach to this.

Comment: @ZachGates, thanks! Never thought there is such an board.

Comment: @cqcn1991 What gives you the idea that "everyone needs to truncate them"? For my purposes I am usually happy with the default Python string representation of floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, np.round works well in this case

```
> from pandas import DataFrame
> import numpy as np
> a = DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=10).reshape((5,2)))
0   1
0   -1.444689   -0.991011
1   1.054962    -0.288084
2   -0.700032   -0.604181
3   0.693142    2.281788
4   -1.647281   -1.309406

> np.round(a,2)
0   1
0   -1.44   -0.99
1   1.05    -0.29
2   -0.70   -0.60
3   0.69    2.28
4   -1.65   -1.31
```

you can also round an individual column by simply overwriting with rounded values:

```
> a[1] = np.round(a[1],3)
> a
0   1
0   0.028320    -1.104
1   -0.121453   -0.179
2   -1.906779   -0.347
3   0.234835    -0.522
4   -0.309782   0.129
```

Comment: So, in most cases, you calculate first and the parse the result? or just leave it there? My main concern is that the `x` looks really `ugly`.

Comment: Usually, I find that I only round at the final stage when i'm intending to "display" my result as a table and leave my results as is until then, if you don't want to actually change the numbers but still want them to "look nice" what you can do is use the pandas display options.
`pandas.set_option('precision', 3)`