# Format Input to Decimal Price in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, dictionary, data-structures

I have the following `dictionary`

```
dic_ = {"name": "John", "age": 42, "budget":"50000", "gender":"male"}
```

**Goal**: I want to format the input of `budget` to always to make sure it is always

`GOOD FORMAT` : `50000.00` (THIS FORMAT WITH `.00` AT THE END, NO COMMA, NO SPACE)

If the input is ever entered with any following below:
`BAD FORMAT`

`50 000` or `50000` or `50,000`

reformat to the `GOOD FORMAT`

Here is what I have tried so far but its not working:

```
def format_(data):
  raw_budget = data["budget"]
  if " " in raw_budget and raw_budget[-3:] != ".00":
    result = raw_budget.replace(" ", "") + ".00"
  if "," in raw_budget and raw_budget[-3:] != ".00":
    result = raw_budget.replace(",", "") + ".00"
  if raw_budget[-3:] == ".00":
    result = raw_budget
  else:
    result = raw_budget + ".00"
  return result
```

The problem with the function above is that its not all correct as it does not cover all the cases and edges, is there a better way to achieve this and make sure all the cases above are covered?

Comment: What if the budget is `"103.50"`?

Comment: Your function has a parameter called `data` but that parameter is never used?

Comment: Have you considered string formatting? convert to number then to string?

Comment: @stef any suggestion in terms of codes

Comment: @TomMyddeltyn will be glad to see any suggestion in terms of codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to normalize your input and detect if a comma is used to separate decimal places or thousands:

```
inputs = ["50 000", "50000", "50,000", "103.50", "      103  .  50", "103,5  0"]


def _format(inp):
    # use only allowed characters
    str_budget = ''.join([x for x in str(inp) if x in "0123456798.,"])

    if ',' in str_budget and str_budget.index(',') == len(str_budget) - 3:
        # if comma used as decimal separator change it
        str_budget = str_budget.replace(',', '.')
    else:
        # if comma used thousands separator
        str_budget = str_budget.replace(',', '')
    return "%.2f" % float(str_budget)


for inp in inputs:
    print(_format(inp))
```

Out:

```
50000.00
50000.00
50000.00
103.50
103.50
103.50
```

Comment: But what if decimals >2? Not sure what the OP expects, but this falls apart then I think.

Comment: @Tom Myddeltyn: Yes, in the end it is still guessing. There might be always edge case uncovered: `10.103,5 00 0` vs `10,103.5 00 0`. And there are countries that use a dot to separate decimals others use a comma. [Wiki: Decimal separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Countries_using_decimal_comma)

Comment: Right I know that. Unfortunately, I think you need to know that about the data ahead of time unless it is formatted uniformly across the data and can determine it that way.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer for my own understanding, why are we turning a string into a float so it can be a string anyhow?

Comment: Good question, decimal point formatting allows floats only, same for `print(f"{str_budget:.2f}")`. You'll recieve an TypeError when trying to format a `str`

Comment: I think it's a dangerous and clumsy idea to try to replace some commas and dots manually, then hope for everything to work out. There are library functions relying on the system's locale designed specifically to avoid that kind of trouble.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to format a string. This string represents a number. The easiest way is to convert the string to a number, then use standard string formatting:

```py
def toCorrectBudgetFormat(s):
  return "{:.2f}".format(float(s))

print(toCorrectBudgetFormat("300.1678"))
# 300.17
print(toCorrectBudgetFormat("300"))
# 300.00
```

Note how `300.1678` was rounded to the closest two-digits-after-comma number `300.17`. If you don't like rounding to closest and would prefer systematically rounding up or rounding down, you can replace `float(s)` with `math.floor(float(s)*100)/100` or `math.ceil(float(s)*100)/100`.

**See also:**

- [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting);
- [Standard format specifiers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/#standard-format-specifiers);
- [How to turn a float number like 293.4662543 into 293.47 in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914725/how-to-turn-a-float-number-like-293-4662543-into-293-47-in-python).

Comment: Important to know that this can round up a number. vs truncation (or floor)

Comment: Thanks @TomMyddeltyn, I added a paragraph with your remark.

Answer (score 0):

In python3 it is possible to use [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) like this :

```py
f"{value:.2f}"
```

Example :

```py
print(f"{500:.2f}")
500.00
```